# Criteria for silicone utensils

Tags: baking, equipment

What are some things to look out for when looking to purchase silicone utensil sets?

Comment: Utensil sets - as in "what should be part of the set" or "parameters like heat resistance" or "ergonomics" or.... Please clarify, else this is either "unclear" or "too broad", imho.

Comment: What sort of sets?  Are we talking about sets of silicone scrapers, or spatulas (turners) and such?

Answer (score 2):

I submitted an edit to fix up your question because it sounded like a product recommendation.  Can you also provide more info, like what you would be using them for?

Here are a few characteristics I looked for in my recent purchase:

- Thickness - thinner spatulas would be easier to slide under food
- Stiffness in the handle - better for stirring soups, stews
- Blade shape - for getting into the corners and curves of your jars, bowls, and pans

Of course, read up on reviews of the products you're researching.  These will attest to build quality, construction, ease of use for other customers.